# Annotation / Text at cross between y-label and title in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am struggling for almost a complete day now with positioning a simple text field in a matplotlib subplot. My goal is to position a one-letter text field (e.g., "A") at the top left of a subplot. However, it should be outside of the plot.

I know that I can position it relative to the axes by e.g., manually specifiying values. Yet, my goal is to automatize this process as I have to process a large amount of figures.

My idea was to use the x-coordinate of the ylabel and the y-coordinate of the title -- yet, with not much success.

To give an example:

[image]

I would like to add "A" exactly where "ylabel" and "Title" would imaginary cross.

Comment: can you show the code where you tried using the x\y coordinates of label and title? You might just be missing some transformations to make it work.

Comment: I tried a variety of things. Most basically: `ax.yaxis.label.get_position()` and simultaniously for the title. The result though is x=0.0, y = 0.5 which does not apply if I use ax1.transAxes for adding the text. I then tried various other transformation shenanigans which did not work and which I have not saved.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to do the same thing just now and couldn't find anything helpful in the docs or after googling, so ended up looking at the code for tight_layout in tight_layout.py under the matplotlib directory. The function you're looking for is **axes.get_tightbbox**. Here's how to do what you want:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import TransformedBbox

fig = plt.gcf()
ax  = fig.gca()
renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()

# Get the bounding box in pixel coordinates
bb = ax.get_tightbbox(renderer)

# Transform the bbox to figure coordinates
bb = TransformedBbox(bb, fig.transFigure.inverted())

# Write text at the top left corner using figure coordinates.
plt.text(bb.x0, bb.y1, "HELLO", transform=fig.transFigure, verticalalignment="top", horizontalalignment="left")
```